# Insert external XML file into templavoila DS?

Tags: typo3, templavoila

How one can insert/load external XML files into Templavoila static data structure? I have a lot of stuff for each field, mainly TypoScript settings, which can be generated outside. I want insert them into static DS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if it's possible at all (but must to say, that didn't try it never), anyway maybe better option is mapping fields as a `path to the TypoScript object` - and then you can easily divide it to smaller TypoScript templates and additionally externalize templates into `*.ts` files.

Comment: You're right, mapping TS through `lib.filed` is another possibility. I just look for XML solution, if possible.